# How to find malicious images in server?

Tags: xss, shellcode, session-management

Recently my Drupal site on a Linux server has been targeted by session hijacking attacks. I guess the attacks were originated from images containing malicious code which where uploaded to the web root because I have found some of the crafted images by looking at uploaded files. 
So I am wondering how best to find all those images?

Comment: Images or html tags to images? Look through your web data to find img tags with CSRF code.

Comment: I mean images (.jpg, .gif, etc)

Comment: How can an image compromise a system (except exploiting bugs in the rendering software)? What is an image with malicious code exactly for you?

Comment: When an uploaded image was able to compromise security, then there certainly was another bug which contributed to the attack by causing the image to be interpreted as something different (like a PHP script). You should rather look into fixing that vulnerability. Is your Drupal version up-to-date?

Comment: @Phillipp, In this question I am just trying to find the symptoms not the causes.

Answer (score 2):

If you know what you're looking for, then you simply examine the data within the file to see if it matches the pattern you're looking for. How you do that depends on what sort of pattern it is; you could view the files in a text editor (for text-based patterns) a hex-viewer (for binary patterns) or you could write (or otherwise acquire) a program that will tease these patterns out of the files and present you with a report.

On the other hand, if you *don't* know what you're looking for, then you're obviously not going to find it.

Comment: I was hoping that there are some well-known patterns/functions that one can look for using find etc.

Comment: Not really. "Malicious image" could mean any number of things, not necessarily all related.